How to show the table after i submitted the button
Im using laravel and i've done hide the table using css. After that, I'm use javascript to show table that I'm following... Here what i done so far:
function checkData() {
    var button = document.getElementById("submit");
    var table = document.getElementById("controlTable");

// Then, add an event listener to the button
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // When the button is clicked, show the table
    table.style.display = "block";
    });
    return button;

#controlTable{
    display: none;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ $title }} Page </title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/index.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    @yield('body')
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/index.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>

<div class="col-lg-12 mt-3">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="submit" onclick="confirm('Are You Sure?');">Check Data</button>
    </div>

<!-- Table Section -->
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered border border-secondary" id="controlTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>Client Name</th>
                    <th>January</th>
                    <th>February</th>
                    <th>March</th>
                    <th>April</th>
                    <th>May</th>
                    <th>June</th>
                    <th>July</th>
                    <th>August</th>
                    <th>September</th>
                    <th>October</th>
                    <th>November</th>
                    <th>December</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach ($calculates as $calculate)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $calculate->client_candidate }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">ON TIME</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">LATE</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

When i try that, table even not showing. I've been following tutorial many times and i try but still not working. Now I'm stuck, i don't know what is wrong in my code that. Please help me.

You have a handler for clicking the wrap button in the checkData function, but the code does not show that it was called. Either move the listner creation outside the function, or call the function once after it is created (or by the DOM loading event)

Remove display:none in your CSS, then add d-none in your table instead
<table class="table table-bordered border border-secondary d-none" id="controlTable">

This will give your table a display:none style because of bootstrap
Next is use toggle in your element
var table = document.getElementById("controlTable");
... // some code here
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    table.classList.toggle("d-none");
});

This will toggle/add・remove class "d-none" everytime button is clicked.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.d-none { /*manually added the css here but no need to do this since bootstrap already has d-none*/
display:none
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Show Table</button>


<table class="d-none" id="controlTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>


</body>
<script>
var button = document.getElementById("submit");
var table = document.getElementById("controlTable");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    table.classList.toggle("d-none");
});
</script>

</html> 




It's still not working. I don't know what wrong in my code:(

I added some code for you to check. Just add d-none in the table class. then update your javascript button.addEventListener

I also dont see any button with id submit in your question. Are you sure such button was added?

Also what do you mean not working? Did you do what I did in my answer?

Yes...i did. i've been added button with id submit. i'm sorry if my question not very detailed.

Did you try the code that I added?

Not yet...I mean i've tried your code at the first one what you gave me before it's not working...

Its the same code.

Ok...I'll try it once more

You can add id on div which has table and display it none and add id on the submit button and show the table using jquery.
<div class="col-12" id="table" style="display:none;">
  <button class="btn btn-warning" id="show" type="submit">LATE</button>
</div>
 <script>
    $("#show").click(function() {
        $("#table").show();
    });


Try this:
<style>
    #controlTable {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Show Table</button>

<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered border border-secondary" id="controlTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Client Name</th>
                <th>January</th>
                <th>February</th>
                <th>March</th>
                <th>April</th>
                <th>May</th>
                <th>June</th>
                <th>July</th>
                <th>August</th>
                <th>September</th>
                <th>October</th>
                <th>November</th>
                <th>December</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($calculates as $calculate)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $calculate->client_candidate }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">ON TIME</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">LATE</button>
                </td>
                <!-- Repeat similar structure for other months -->
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var button = document.getElementById('submit');
        var table = document.getElementById('controlTable');

        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            table.style.display = 'block';
        });
    });
</script>

Let me know if that’s helps :)
